# Contact us form with ActionMailer routing error with Rails 4

Tags: rest, ruby-on-rails-4, routes, actionmailer

I'm relatively new to this. I'm trying to route a URL to form and then, that form to shoot off the contact email. This is the error that I'm getting.
And when I rake the routes I see that in fact there is no such this as POST for send_mail. But I'm not sure why there isn't one in the first place. And I'm not sure how to put one in...

```
Routing Error
No route matches [POST] "/send_mail"

Rails.root: /home/nadia/blog
```

This is my contact_controller:

```
1 class ContactController < ApplicationController
2   def new
3   end
4
5   def send_mail
6     name = params[:name]
7     email = params[:email]
8     message = params [:message]
9     ContactUs.contact_email(name, email, message).deliver
10     redirect_to contact_path, notice: 'Message Sent'
11   end
```

This is my app/mailer/contact_us.rb

```
1 class ContactUs < ActionMailer::Base
2   default to: "my@email.com"
3   default from: "my@email.com"
4
5   def contact_email (name, email, message)
6     @name = name
7     @email = email
8     @message = message
9
10     mail(from: name, subject: 'Contact')
11   end
12 end
13
```

Please let me know if there any additional files I can show you
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your routes.rb

`post '/send_mail' => 'contact#send_mail'`

You should read the [Rails routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html) for more info

Comment: Thank you! I think it might have fixed that issue.... That unfortunately gives me another error- "message = params [:message]" Arguement Error... :S Oh dear.

Answer (score 0):

simply add this in routes.rb

```
post '/send_mail' => 'contact#send_mail'
```

Comment: Thank you! I think it might have fixed that issue.... That unfortunately gives me another error-  "message = params [:message]" Arguement Error... :S Oh dear.